# use of built in forms and views like PasswordChangeForm in django1.3

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms, django-1.3

I am new to django,In **django1.3** how can I use the Built-in forms like **PasswordChangeForm ,PasswordResetForm**  etc  and the same using  **built-in views**.Can any one share some liks or codes ,ideas,am absolutely .new to Django,Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding forgot-password feature to Django admin site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272002/adding-forgot-password-feature-to-django-admin-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django by default has all these forms built in views. For all those features, all you need to do is to, point them at relevant URL positions, that map to the specific views.

This question has already been answered:

[Adding forgot-password feature to Django admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272002/adding-forgot-password-feature-to-django-admin-site/2272285#2272285)

Comment: I add url(r'^passreset/$',auth_views.password_reset,name='forgot_password1'), to my url.py .                                                  But I got an exception            NoReverseMatch at /passresett/     "Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found"

Comment: Have you added django.contrib.auth into your settings.INSTALLED_APPS?